# Grammar to make unnamed instance

Tags: c++, hash, initialization, instance, temporary

I'm making hashing function for `pair < int,int >` key.

Anyway, I found the following implementation that uses `std::hash<>` :

```
typedef struct hasher_t {

        template <class T1, class T2>
        size_t operator()(const pair<T1,T2>& key) const {
            //standard hasher for T1, T2
            
            auto h1 = std::hash<T1>()(key.first);   //also possible
            auto h2 = std::hash<T2>()(key.second); //also possible
            
            /*
            auto h1 = std::hash<T1>{}(key.first);
            auto h2 = std::hash<T2>{}(key.second);
            */
            return h1 ^ (h2 - 1);
        }

    } hasher;
```

`std::hash<T1>()` and `std::hash<T1>{}` both work, but I don't know why this works.

I even cannot find a reference article for this.

I guess that both of them make literally 'unnamed temporal instance' for class `std::hash<T1>`, and call the `operator()(T1)`  method. Is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both construct temporary `std::hash` and then call `operator()` on the temporary object.

`std::hash<T1>()` performes [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization),

> 1,5) when a nameless temporary object is created with the initializer consisting of an empty pair of parentheses `or braces (since C++11)`;

The temporary is initialized by the default constructor.

`std::hash<T1>{}` performes [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (since C++11),

> 2) initialization of an unnamed temporary with a *braced-init-list*

As the effect the temporary is also [value-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) by the default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

`std::hash<T>` is a type not a function.You can consider it as a **functor**. So you have to create an instance of it.

To answer your question, yes, both ways make an object of `std::hash<T>` and initialize it calling the `()` operator.

`std::hash<T1>()` does initialization using parenthesis. It is also known as **value initialization**.

`std::hash<T1>{}` is initialization using curly braces. In `auto h1 = std::hash<T1>{}(key.first);` what happens is `{}` creates an instance of `std::hash<T1>` and then `(key.first)` calls operator `()` on your instance. This is also called **aggregate initialization** or [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

> In C++11 and onward, you can use std::hash{} (ie, braces
>   instead of parentheses) to build an object.